# Generate random 16 bit number in java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a random 16 bit number in java. I know how to generate random number for given range. can any one help how to generate a 16 bit random number

Comment: Have you tried looking around? What have you found? And if you know the number is 16 bits, you can easily calculate the range...

Comment: Generate a random number and mask off 16 bits of it? - hey, it works ;-)

Comment: If by range you mean a numeric range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean `random.nextInt(1 << 16)` or `random.nextInt(1 << 16) + Short.MIN_VALUE;`

Answer (score 7):

A 16 bit number a binary number with `16` digits. So it will be in the range

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0
1111 1111 1111 1111 = 65535 (2^16-1)
```

So, you can do:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(65536); // 65536 will not be considered, return integer in range [0,65535]
```

which, according to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29), will

> Return a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value **(exclusive)**...

Answer (score 3):

`Short` is a `16bit`

You can call Random class to generate random number on the range of `Short.MAX_VALUE`, which is around `0-65535`. by adding the `Short.MAX_VALUE` and `Short.MIN_VALUE`

**sample:**

```
new Random().nextInt(1 + Short.MAX_VALUE - Short.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: This isn't right. First of all, the upper bound for `nextInt()` is *exclusive*. In addition, `Short.MAX_VALUE` is actually [32767](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html).

Comment: @user3580294 short min is 32768 and short max is 32767 two's compliment

Comment: That's true, but `nextInt()`'s upper bound is *exclusive*. So your method will never actually return 65535. Also, you forgot a close parenthesis.

Comment: I think you mean `1 + Short.MAX_VALUE - Short.MIN_VALUE` or just `1 << 16`

Comment: @PeterLawrey same result. for your first sample.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin But simpler.  Your use of Math.abs() is flawed as it assumes MIN_VALUE must be negative, if it were positive, the range would be wrong, so lets just assume MIN_VALUE is negative. BTW using subtraction is also correct if MIN_VALUE were positive.

Comment: BTW `1 << 15` works for 15 bits, and `1 << 17` works for 17 bits.  It is more generic and simpler.